# Wicket - Sort items in a Palette

Tags: sorting, wicket, palette

i'm looking for a hint how to sort a palette.

1) Sorting the selected items (for example alphabetical): When you select an item from the left side and add it to the right side, the right side should be sorted on every change.

2) If you remove items from the right side, they return to the left side. Right now they are simply added to the last position at the bottom of the palette. I want to to sort the items on change.

Answer (score 0):

You could monkey-patch Wicket.Palette.moveHelper() in palette.js to reorder the items on each change.